# Shortening a long if/test string comparison

Tags: scripting, test

I am comparing multiple strings in bash. Currently I have a script that looks like this:

```
    if [ "$f" != "A-C" ] && [ "$f" != "D-F" ] && [ "$f" != "G-I" ] && [ "$f" != "J-L" ] && [ "$f" != "M-O" ] && [ "$f" != "P-R" ] && [ "$f" != "S-U" ] && [ "$f" != "V-X" ] && [ "$f" != "Y&Z" ] && [ "$f" != "#" ]; then #if f is a directory
```

How can I shorten this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with something like this:

```
[[ "$f" != +(A-C|D-F|G-I|J-L|M-O|P-R|S-U|V-X|Y&Z|#) ]]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes on the right hand side (there's nothing special in `A-C` to quote, it's not a character class without the brackets). `@(foo|bar)` to match exactly once, with `+` it'll match e.g. `A-CJ-L`